# Restarted my server and started getting this error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, digital-ocean, forever

I resized my Digital ocean droplet (Permanently) This required I powered off my droplet and then powered on again. When I visit the webpage I get a typical NGINX page saying that I have succesfully installed NGINX, the web app can no longer be seen

I did a mup logs -f to see what is going on and I am continually getting this error.

I am not sure what is wrong and it looks like something is off with my cron jobs but I am not sure what. Any ideas:

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] error: Script restart attempt #75[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] {"line":"63","file":"synced-cron-server.js","message":"SyncedCron: Scheduled \"Email Weekly Todos for Mentors\" next run @Mon Nov 30 2015 07:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)","time":{"$date":1448741207434},"level":"info"}[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] {"line":"63","file":"synced-cron-server.js","message":"SyncedCron: Scheduled \"Weekly Push Notifications to students\" next run @Sun Nov 29 2015 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)","time":{"$date":1448741207437},"level":"info"}[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] events.js:72[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
at listen (net.js:1065:10)
at net.js:1147:9
at dns.js:72:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
```

Any ideas would help a lot

Comment: This is telling you something is already bound to a port that you're trying to bind to: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`.

Comment: @davejagoda so how can i kill what is running on the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issues by setting the app file in sites-enabled folder to listen to port 3000. I think it was listening to 80 by default and conflicting with nginx